# Can't import the named export error on building angular angular-ng-autocomplete

Tags: angular, angular-cli

This happens on `ng build` and I tried changing the ng-angular-autocomplete version but to no avail.

```
#15 285.8 Error: ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 239:87-105
#15 285.8 Can't import the named export 'ɵɵpureFunction1' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
#15 285.8     at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency._getErrors (/usr/local/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:88:6)
#15 285.8     at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.getErrors (/usr/local/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:68:16)
#15 285.8     at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (/usr/local/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1463:22)
#15 285.8     at /usr/local/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1258:10
#15 285.8     at _next0 (eval at create (/usr/local/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:32:1)
#15 285.8     at eval (eval at create (/usr/local/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:45:1)
#15 285.8     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
#15 285.8     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
#15 285.8  @ ./src/app/pages/dashboard/ta/ta-details/ta-details.component.ts
#15 285.8  @ ./src/app/pages/pages-routing.module.ts
#15 285.8  @ ./src/app/pages/pages.module.ts
#15 285.8  @ ./src/app/app-routing.module.ts
#15 285.8  @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
#15 285.8  @ ./src/main.ts
#15 285.8  @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

There are multiple errors similar to the above but all pointing to modules that use the `ng-angular-autocomplete` library. Also, this had been working without issue for a long time until I tried building today. Last build was 7 days ago on the same codebase and it was successful.

Please find the package.json

```
{
  "name": "sample",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@akveo/ng2-completer": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.9",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.9.0",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^1.2.0",
    "@nebular/auth": "^7.0.0",
    "@nebular/theme": "^7.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.1.2",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.2",
    "angular-datatables": "^12.0.0",
    "angular-ng-autocomplete": "^2.0.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.25",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.1.0",
    "electron": "^11.3.0",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.22",
    "intl-tel-input": "^17.0.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "metismenujs": "^1.3.0",
    "ng-bootstrap": "^1.6.3",
    "ng-click-outside": "^8.0.0",
    "ng2-completer": "^9.0.1",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^1.7.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
    "ngx-captcha": "^9.0.1",
    "ngx-electron": "^2.2.0",
    "ngx-indexed-db": "^9.1.2",
    "ngx-intl-tel-input": "^3.1.1",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^5.5.3",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "recordrtc": "^5.6.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "smooth-scrollbar": "^8.6.3",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.1.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.9",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.20",
    "@types/electron": "^1.6.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.6",
    "@types/node": "^16.4.9",
    "@types/recordrtc": "^5.6.6",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  }
}
```

Update: Tried reverting to earlier states of code which were all successfully built. Each of them fails right now with the same error. Removed all usages for `ng-angular-autocomplete` from the project and the build is successful.

Comment: What version of angular and autocomplete are you using ?

Comment: @GRD Updated the package.json in the question

Comment: I do not see its because of autoComplete  package.

Comment: Yes, the versions appear to be matched. Not sure whats going wrong. Earlier builds with the same version were successful.

Comment: Have you tried deleting /node_modules folder and then re-running `npm install` in case there's some corruption going on or something?

Comment: @ChrisW. I am using docker, so Im deleting and re-creating the entire container - which should create the node_modules from scratch each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use version 2.0.7.

```
yarn add angular-ng-autocomplete@2.0.7
```

or

```
npm i angular-ng-autocomplete@2.0.7
```

(no need to clear node_modules folder)

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]